# How can I get sum of all permutations with repetition using VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have seen questions similar to this but have not gotten the answer I need. Using predefined numbers, I am trying to figure out the best combination of those numbers to get as close to the answer I want as possible, but it doesn't need to give the exact answer.

Lets say I start 2 given angles (1.2 & 1.4) and I need output value close to 6.45, what I want is to find the best combination of those two numbers to give me a number that is close to the output. So in this case in would read 1.2 + 1.2 + 1.2 + 1.4 + 1.4 = 6.4. And my output would tell me how many of each number is needed to get that answer. So 3 of 1.2 and 2 of 1.4.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The number of possible combinations of n objects taken r times is n^r .Being a relatively small number for small n and r (if n=2 and r=10, there are 1024 possible combinations), brute force iterative attack is viable. When all possible combinations are exhausted and no solution target is found, sort the solutions and take the one with the smallest possible distance from target. Or start with small r and if no solution is found, increase r. The max r to try is when min(objects)*r > target

Comment: Try something like this: `Dim v1 = 1.2D Dim v2 = 1.4D Dim refVal = 6.45D  Dim min = Math.Min(v1, v2) Dim max = Math.Max(v1, v2) Dim first = CInt((refVal - min) / max) Dim second = CInt(Math.Ceiling((refVal - (max * first)) / min)) Dim part1 = Math.Abs(refVal - ((max * first) + (min * second))) Dim part2 = Math.Abs(refVal - ((min * first) + (max * second))) Dim result As (maxMul As Integer, minMul As Integer) = If((part1 < part2), (first, second), (second, first))`

Comment: The result is given by the sum of the two values multiplied by the two values found: `Dim number As Decimal = (max * result.maxMul) + (min * result.minMul)`. So `(1.4 * maxMul) + (1.2 * minMul)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class `probe` that could look like this:

```
<DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplayValue}")>
Public Class Probe

    'Constructors

    Public Sub New(lowValue As Decimal, highValue As Decimal, targetValue As Decimal, lowValueCount As Int32)
        Me.LowValue = lowValue
        Me.HighValue = highValue
        Me.TargetValue = targetValue
        Me.LowValueCount = lowValueCount
        Dim myRemainder As Decimal = targetValue - (lowValue * lowValueCount)
        If (myRemainder < 0) Then
            HighValueCount = 0
        Else
            Dim myHighValueCountFraction As Decimal = myRemainder / highValue
            Dim myHighValueCountLow As Int32 = CInt(Math.Truncate(myHighValueCountFraction))
            HighValueCount = myHighValueCountLow
            Dim myDiff1 As Decimal = Difference
            HighValueCount += 1
            Dim myDiff2 As Decimal = Difference
            If (myDiff1 < myDiff2) Then HighValueCount -= 1
        End If
    End Sub

    'Public Properties

    Public ReadOnly Property LowValueCount As Int32
    Public ReadOnly Property HighValueCount As Int32

    Public ReadOnly Property LowValue As Decimal
    Public ReadOnly Property HighValue As Decimal

    Public ReadOnly Property TargetValue As Decimal

    Public ReadOnly Property ResultValue As Decimal
        Get
            Return (LowValueCount * LowValue) + (HighValueCount * HighValue)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Difference As Decimal
        Get
            Dim myResult As Decimal = TargetValue - ResultValue
            If (myResult < 0) Then myResult *= -1D
            Return myResult
        End Get
    End Property

    'Public Methods

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"({LowValueCount} * {LowValue}) + ({HighValueCount} * {HighValue}) = {ResultValue}"
    End Function

    'Private Properties

    Private ReadOnly Property DebuggerDisplayValue As String
        Get
            Return ToString()
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

and the solver that might look like this:

```
Public Class PermutationSolver

    Public Shared Function Solve(lowValue As Decimal, highValue As Decimal, targetValue As Decimal) As Probe
        'Validate args
        If (lowValue <= 0D) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(NameOf(lowValue), lowValue, "The value must be positive and greater than zero.")
        If (highValue <= 0D) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(NameOf(highValue), highValue, "The value must be positive and greater than zero.")
        If (targetValue <= 0D) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(NameOf(targetValue), targetValue, "The value must be positive and greater than zero.")
        'Normalize args
        If (lowValue > highValue) Then
            Dim myTempValue As Decimal = lowValue
            lowValue = highValue
            highValue = myTempValue
        End If
        'Compare probes
        Dim myResult As New Probe(lowValue, highValue, targetValue, 0)
        If (myResult.Difference = 0) Then Return myResult
        Dim myMaxIndex As Int32 = CInt(Math.Truncate(targetValue / lowValue)) + 1
        For i As Int32 = 1 To myMaxIndex
            Dim myProbe As New Probe(lowValue, highValue, targetValue, i)
            If (myProbe.Difference = 0) Then Return myProbe
            If (myProbe.Difference < myResult.Difference) Then myResult = myProbe
        Next
        'Return best match
        Return myResult
    End Function

End Class
```

This way you don't need much iterations (a maximum of `(TargetValue / LowValue) + 2`) and also get a correct value if the difference to the target value is negativ.